# first and last statements in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to do a count on the number of births. the data looks this way

```
ID        date 
101     2016-01-01
101     2016-02-01
101     2016-02-01
102     2015-03-02
102     2016-04-01
103     2016-02-08
```

So now i want to create a count based on the date 
the output expected is this way

```
ID        date         count
101     2016-01-01      1
101     2016-02-01      2
101     2016-02-01      2
102     2015-03-02      1
102     2016-04-01      2
103     2016-02-08      1
```

I am trying to do it by first and last and also the count from proc sql but I am missing something here.

```
data temp; 
set temp; 

by ID DATE notsorted; 

if first.date then c=1; 
else c+1; 


if first.ID then m=1; 
else m+1; 

run;
```

Comment: Please explain your output table. I don't understand the logic behind your COUNT variable. If it is supposed to be a count by ID and date then your last two rows are wrong.

Comment: Hey oh yes, sorry wrongly entered, I corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with your original approach

```
data x;
input id : 3. date : ddmmyy10.;
 FORMAT DATE ddmmyy10.; 
datalines;
101 01-01-2016
101 02-01-2016
101 02-01-2016
102 03-02-2015
102 04-01-2016
103 02-08-2016
;

run;

data x; 
set x; 

by ID DATE notsorted; 

if first.ID then c=0; /*reset count every time id changes*/
if first.date then c+1; /*raise count when date changes*/

run;
```

produces
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely require to use first?

I would use proc freq to achieve this

```
data have;
   infile datalines delimiter='09'x; 
   input ID $ date $10. ;
   datalines;
101 2016-01-01
101 2016-02-01
101 2016-02-01
102 2015-03-02
102 2016-04-01
103 2016-02-08
;run;

proc freq DATA=have NOPRINT;
    TABLES ID * date / OUT=want(drop=percent);
run;
```

creates this:

```
ID date count
101 2016-01-01  1
101 2016-02-01  2
102 2015-03-02  1
102 2016-04-01  1
103 2016-02-08  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce COUNT in the datastep you will have to use the double DOW. The dataset is SET twice. First time to count rows by ID and date. Second time to output all rows.

```
data out;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.date); 
    set test ;
    by ID date;
    if first.date then count = 1;
    else count + 1;
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.date); 
    set test ;
    by ID date;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add RETAIN statement in your data-step.

> ```
> data temp; 
> set temp; 
> retain c m 0;
>
> by ID DATE notsorted; 
>
> if first.date then c=1; 
> else c+1; 
>
>
> if first.ID then m=1; 
> else m+1; 
>
> run;
> ```

Comment: You do not need an explicit RETAIN when using sum statement (c+1).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have edited the previous code. Hopefully this will suit your needs. Just make sure your date variable is in numeric or calendar format so that you can sort your table by ID and date first.

```
data want;
set have;
by id date;

if first.date then count=0;
count+1;

run;
```

Comment: Hi I did the same thing, but the main problem is if it is the second delivery of the ID and has triplets in the second delivery then this goes wrong..the order or the number of the delivery should be 2 instead of 3